# I am sorry that I hit you

Tags: grammar

1. I am sorry that I hit you.
2. I am sorry for having hit you.
3. I am sorry for hitting you.

Are all these possibly talking about a past event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have natural expressions for all nine combinations of present, past, and future of the regret compared to the regretted action.  Some of my examples rely on backshifting tenses for reported speech, and two (past and future regret, present action) use the enduring present for an ongoing situation.

Present regret:
present action: I am sorry this is hurting you.
past action: I am sorry that I hurt you.
future action:  I am sorry that this will hurt you.

Past regret:
present action: He said that he was sorry that he is hurting her.
past action: I realized that I was sorry that I hurt you.
future action: He said that he was sorry that he would hurt you.

Future regret:
present action:  I will eventually be sorry that you are gone. 
past action:  I'll be sorry tomorrow that she has left.
future action: How will I be able to be sorry about your absence if you won't go away?

Answer (score 0):

Yes all of them are referring to a past event. The usage of *I am sorry* is use to apologize for something that has already happened. Definition of sorry:

> Feeling regret, compunction, sympathy, pity, etc.:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sorry

Well you can't really feel sorry if you haven't done something wrong, right? Well, it is somehow possible to somehow apologize for the future, but that would be out of the context of this question.

Comment: *I am sorry* is a present tense statement of how you are currently feeling.  The reason for that current feeling may likely be something that happened in the past, but could also be, as you say, because of something you know is coming that can't be avoided.

Comment: @Jim Like this? **I'm sorry Mr. Bond, but I have to kill you now.** I'll leave you tied up to this machine which will activate when the sun hits this sensor, which starts this other device spinning, which... well eventually it kills you. And now we'll all leave you alone since I don't think you'll escape this, despite the fact that you've escaped every single trap previously. James: "Could you at least hand me my cigarettes, lighter, pen, and watch, so I can relax and take a note or two?"  "Well I don't see any harm in that, here!  Good day, Mr. Bond!  For me that is... not for you.  Bwahaha!"